# '\' Getting Stripped Automatically In StringObject.ReplaceAll method in Java

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-string, replaceall, unicode-escapes

I am using Jre 1.6.
I am executing the following lines of code:

String unicodeValue = "\u001B"; text = text.replaceAll("" + character, unicodeValue);

Here, text is a string object containing an invalid XML character of Unicode value '\u001B'.
So, I am converting the invalid XML character to its Unicode value to write in the XML.

But on doing text.replaceAll, the '\' is getting stripped and the character is replaced by 'u001B'.

Can anyone please suggest a way to retain the '\' after replacing the character with its unicode value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`str.replaceAll(regex, repl)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is defined as returning the same as

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

But the [documentation for `replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) says,

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

So this means we need to add several extra layers of escaping:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String unicodeValue = "\u001B";
        String escapedUnicodevalue = "\\\\u001B";
        String text = "invalid" + unicodeValue + "string";

        text = text.replaceAll(unicodeValue, escapedUnicodevalue);

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

prints `invalid\u001Bstring` as desired.

Comment: If you put String unicodeValue = "\\u001B";
then replace the character with the unicodeValue by text = text.replaceAll("" + character, unicodeValue);,
the '\' is getting stripped.

Comment: @HarshdipSingh  In the replacement text, a dollar sign must be encoded as \$ and a backslash as \\ when you want to replace the regex match with an actual dollar sign or backslash. However, backslashes must also be escaped in literal Java strings. So a single dollar sign in the replacement text becomes "\\$" when written as a literal Java string. The single backslash becomes "\\\\". Right again: 4 backslashes to insert a single one.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Answer (score 0):

Use double slash `\\` to represent escaped `\`:

```
String unicodeValue = "\\u001B"; text = text.replaceAll("" + character, unicodeValue);
```

Comment: String unicodeValue = "\\u001B"; text = text.replaceAll("" + character, unicodeValue);
this line is stripping off the '\'. Any idea how to retain the '\' ?

Comment: @HarshdipSingh Try \\\\u001B, if you use text as a regex string.

Answer (score 0):

This ran perfect. I tested it.

```
    char character = 0x1b;
    String unicodeValue = "\\\\u001B"; 
    String text = "invalid " + character + " string";
    System.out.println(text);
    text = text.replaceAll("" + character, unicodeValue);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Just used a concept of RegEx.